# Passwordless SSH on Diskless Linux Cluster

Tags: linux, ssh, nfs

I'm working on diskless Linux Cluster( a server machine, a master machine and 10 x slave machines). Which means the slave machines has no data storage device. I use a NFS server with the collaboration of PXE, DHCP, TFTP and SSH server configured to host the generic boot image for the single system image cluster nodes.
Here is my question:

> How do i store and retrieve the hostkeys for diskless machines in a secure manner?

I came up two solutions.

First, I can store them on the server and export them via nfs to the slave machines. But since NFS is not encrypted this would probably be a security problem.

Second solution: store keys in live cd. Machines will have hostkeys when boot live cd via NFS. But this is not a practical or safe way.

I really need help about this.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `/home/user` folder of diskless station writable. [UnionFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) can be used for this. Also this can be done in initrd by creating tmpfs in RAM, copying current content of `/home/user` there, and mouting this as `/home/user` folder. By doing so you will have writable `/home/user` folder (but all changes will be lost after reboot).

**EDIT**: There is also [Aufs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aufs/) which is re-designed and re-implemented Unionfs.

Once you have this you can have bash script which retrieves necessary files via https ([wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) with authentication) from server or via [scp](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) with hardcoded credentials or key (solely only for this copy procedure).

So, here you have diskless image with writable `/home/user` folder and script which on boot retrieves SSH keys to the `/home/user` folder.

This is abstract description of the solution, but it is 100% possible.

Comment: I didn't hear before UnionFS. It seems very useful. Thak you very much Nikolay.

Comment: Yes, it is very useful. One thing to know - your kernel should support it. You should obtain already patched kernel (may be it is available for your system, like there is one available in Gentoo Linux) or patch kernel manually, compile it and run. And there is [Aufs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aufs/), which is redesigned UnionFS and apparently is better. So, actually, go with AUFS.

Comment: I searched Aufs on the internet after your suggestion and i found Overlayfs (http://askubuntu.com/questions/109413/how-do-i-use-overlayfs). They say it will forcefully replace aufs in Ubuntu 12.04 (I will use ubuntu live cd 12.04). Do you know something about it ? Is it better or easier to use then Aufs ?

Comment: No, I did not hear about Overlayfs before. So, I do not what to say about it...

Comment: +1 for the solution using tmpfs from initrd. Question: Could you just set the `/home/user/.ssh` folder as tmpfs? and could you do that within an NFS mount of `/home/user`? ie each node shares an NFS home directory from some central master server but with each nodes specific /home/user/.ssh folder residing locally in RAM?

Comment: @MrPurple, yes, you can mount your tmpfs to the `/home/user/.ssh` as mountpoint. On your second question - I think for this to work you will have to make NFS mount first, and after that do the `/home/user/.ssh`. Otherwise if you do tmpfs first, the NFS mount could overlay (replace) the contents of your `/home/user/.ssh`

Comment: By using https or scp the transfer of the keys is encrypted but I don't understand why using a set of hard-coded credentials for only this copy is better than just using hard coded credentials? What keeps an attacker from TFTPing themself a copy of the boot image and then requesting the credentials using wget or scp?